# how to scrape divs within their parent div

Tags: python, html, find, scrape

Im trying to scrape a URL and when i run the below code, I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' "

```
url = 'https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/50'

data=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

rows = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': "float: right; width: 900px;"}).find_all('div', 
recursive=False)

print(rows)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: Well, I don't know beautifulSoup. But it seems to me that your real problem is that the first "find" is not finding anything, and is not about finding in parent Div. I surmise there are no div with style "float: right; width:900px". Still not knowing Beautiful Soup, but used to search in DOM, I find quite strange to search on a "style=" criteria. You have to find correctly the parent div first. So far, obviously, you didn't find the "div" in which you intended to "find_all" some other divs.

Comment: @chrslg Thanks for your response. Finding the parent div first worked the magic. Thanks Genius

Comment: did you sovle the problem?

Comment: @louis joseph Yeah I did fam. Thanks for asking